# In app purchases for iOS and Android

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I'm creating a mobile game that'll be released to iOS and Android. Does anyone know of any good in app purchase ane or api?

Comment: Why people still using Adobe AIR to produce iOS Apps? They will be **rejected**, as of November 2014, since Feb 1, 2014. #facepalm

Comment: @Raptor thanks for letting me know. I had no idea smh

Comment: Do not listen to raptor comment. This is just a hateful comment with no base facts whatsoever. AIR app are not rejected on the app store, no announcements that they will be has been made, no reasons that they will ever be exists.

Comment: @Raptor This is 100% incorrect. I have had 3 AIR apps accepted by Apple since early September with another currently awaiting review.

Comment: @Josh Janusch I did a little more research after reading the comment. Some of the AIR apps were rejected due to Apple's new requirement for iOS apps to be compiled in the latest version of Xcode. But you guys are right adobe once again found a way around this :). Sooooo whose going to help me with the in app purchases?

Comment: @BotMaster Have you used in app purchases in any of your AIR apps

Comment: ios 7 is required for any app submitted and ios 8 will be required as of February 2015. Any app submitted not fitting this requirement will be rejected, this has nothing to do with AIR. You can make a app with Xcode and target ios 6 and get it rejected if you want. There's a couple of Inapp purchase ane available. Never used them so google them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Milkman Games or Distriqt. Importantly I would say choose an ANE that is supported with regular updates.

I personally use Distriqt for IAP.

Comment: thanks a million, I really appreciate it. Whats the name of your app? Is it available for download?

Comment: You can try Prime Mover:

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/prime-mover/id595928344?mt=8

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.sm4business.primemover


or Weights Mate:

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/weights-mate/id903005096?mt=8

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.tv.aitch.weightsmate